# Nmap giving different result between Mac OS scan and Linux (Kali) scan

Tags: nmap, virtualization, macos, ports, network-scanners

I try to do a simple TCP scan on an Kubunt VM (is on VirtualBox), from two different OS. 
From the Host (Mac OS system) and from a Kali Linux VM (tried VirtualBox and Parallels also). 
Kali Linux (same result VirtualBox and Parallels) gives:

[image]

From Mac OS (run with root privileges, to simulate the same scan from Kali):

[image]

So run a Nmap scan from Mac OS gives more open ports on the same VM, with the same privilege of scan, etc. 
Mind blowing...

If I scan just a port (from Kali VM) try the 110, the result is that is closed:

[image]

Why is it happening?

Comment: Uh, you scan the VM from the host, then you scan the VM from another VM. Those are very different scans because your approach is different.

Comment: but the Kubunt VM is on the same network.. why is different approach? Why it give different results if I simulate the same behavior. Thanks @schroeder for the fast answer

Comment: The host is not on the same network as the VMs. It's the *host*.

Comment: @schroeder I think you'll need to expand your reasoning there. *Why* would the host be able to see more ports than another VM?

Comment: They were done three days apart according to timestamps. How about running them one after another?

Comment: @postoronnim it's on the same day all the scans (my VM is out of date) and the scans it's on my own PC and local network.
Some more details, the 3 VM are set with bridge network configuration.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you might want to try running both again, to see if you get consistent results. If so, then the hosts are treated differently for whatever reason by the Kubuntu VM.

Comment: So I think they shouldn't be different. There are of course settings that would prevent one vm to even reach another vm, but clearly this is not the case here since both scans show open ports. So I too would suggest running the scans again one after another.

Comment: A quick check you could do is to connect to one of the ports which is only shows as open per the scan from your host. Use netcat or something similar.   If your able to connect to it from your host, but not using your guest, then it sounds like @schroeder is corrrect.

Comment: I've tried to look at this a few ways, and this doesn't look like a security question. You need to understand how the host-to-VM network works, and you need to understand how nmap determines ports. Neither of those things are security-related. And, your results from Dan's test supports my suggestion that the host-to-VM scanning produces different results.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of many reasons. Such as the following:

- Network Layout
- Antivirus Software
- IDS/IPS
- Intermediate Network Devices
- The version of your Nmap's
- ..etc

In your case, it seems like you are using your MAC OS as the host. While Kali Linux is a VM with the MAC host. If you have an Anti Virus software or Strict Firewall rules enabled, they could be dropping the requests begin generated by your KALI VM-nmap scan. Which is in turn giving you different results on the different hosts.

In Order to verify this hypothesis, you can try to boot up Kali as a host and try scanning the "said" machine again with the same versions of Nmap.